# C# Swagger generated client with domain authentication

Tags: c#, rest, swagger, swagger-codegen

We have a simple rest API exposed with Swagger UI. We usually copy-paste the raw definition to editor.swagger.io, and generate a C# client. The generated code works very well - but we work in a **Windows AD environment**, and we cannot find any way to tell the client to use the **current user credentials** during the communication. So the IIS hosted rest API throws Unauthorized exception - as it is set to Windows authentication mode.

Is it possible to use the generated client this way? Any option to add to the API definition to generate such a client?

Writing a client manually is easy:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
...
```

but we would like to generate it ... but the Configuration contains nothing about credentials ... :(

```
public static IO.Swagger.Api.IBookingApi GetBookingApiWebApi()
{
    var basePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["web.api.url"];
    var api = new BookingApi(basePath);
    return api;
}
```

Thanks in advance...